# Transform rotate() not working as expected in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, css-transforms

I'm attempting to animate a 3D cube using CSS transforms. In Chrome and Safari this works as expected. In Firefox however, the 'lids' of the cube, which are rotated 90deg, don't display correctly until they are rotated back to 0deg.

I thought this might be an issue with overflow () but this doesn't seem to help. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong!

Here's my code so far:
https://codepen.io/simonandywilson/pen/RwGrgYJ

```css
html body {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #808080;
}

.leftContainer,
.rightContainer {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.leftContainer {
  z-index: 99;
  transform-origin: bottom right;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  transform: rotateX(-25deg) rotateY(-45deg);
  animation: flatternLeft 2s 4s 1 forwards;
}

.rightContainer {
  transform-origin: bottom left;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  transform: rotateX(-25deg) rotateY(45deg);
  animation: flatternRight 2s 4s 1 forwards;
}

.face {
  position: relative;
  width: 50vh;
  height: 50vh;
  background: #ffffff;
  border: solid 2px #0000ff;
}

.leftTop {
  transform-origin: bottom right;
  transform: rotateX(90deg);
  animation: rotateLid 2s 1 forwards;
}

.rightTop {
  transform-origin: bottom left;
  transform: rotateX(90deg);
  animation: rotateLid 2s 2s 1 forwards;
}

@keyframes rotateLid {
  from {
    transform: rotateX(90deg);
  }

  to {
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
  }
}

@keyframes flatternLeft {
  from {
    transform: rotateX(-25deg) rotateY(-45deg);
  }

  to {
    transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
  }
}

@keyframes flatternRight {
  from {
    transform: rotateX(-25deg) rotateY(45deg);
  }

  to {
    transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="leftContainer">
  <div class="cube">
    <div class="face leftTop"></div>
    <div class="face leftBottom"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="rightContainer">
  <div class="cube">
    <div class="face rightTop"></div>
    <div class="face rightBottom"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else that has the same problem, I've discovered that the issue comes from Firefox not passing `transform-style: preserve-3d` to each child. Adding this property to the wrapper element fixes the issue:

https://codepen.io/simonandywilson/pen/WNRRwKP

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what is causing the issue but I would do it differently with less of code and without the issue:

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  background: #808080;
}
.container {
  display: grid;
  margin:10vh auto;
  width:80vh;
  grid-template-rows:repeat(2,40vh);
  grid-template-columns:repeat(2,1fr);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: rotateX(-25deg);
}

.container > * {
  background: #ffffff;
  border: solid 2px #0000ff;
  transform-origin: bottom right;
}
.container > *:nth-child(even) {
   transform-origin: bottom left;
}

.leftTop { 
  transform: rotateY(-45deg) rotateX(90deg);
  animation:
   leftop linear 1s forwards,
   face linear 1s forwards 2s;
}
.leftBottom {
   transform: rotateY(45deg) rotateX(90deg);
   animation:
     leftBottom linear 1s forwards 1s,
     face linear 1s forwards 2s;
}
.rightTop {
  transform: rotateY(-45deg);
  animation:face linear 1s forwards 2s;
}
.rightBottom {
  transform: rotateY(45deg);
  animation:face linear 1s forwards 2s;
}
@keyframes leftop{
   to {transform: rotateY(-45deg) rotateX(0deg)}
}
@keyframes leftBottom{
   to {transform: rotateY(45deg) rotateX(0deg)}
}
@keyframes face{
   to {transform: rotateY(0deg)}
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="leftTop"></div>
  <div class="leftBottom"></div>
  <div class="rightTop"></div>
  <div class="rightBottom"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this messes up the animation when the sides unfold together, thank you for trying though. I've figured out that this issue was due to firefox not passing transform-style: preserve-3d to each child

Comment: @wrgt Where you see the mess? I reproduced the exact same animation as yours